# Forbidden access while deleting row from displayed table on html and record in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a table in mysql database and displayed the content of the table on html page. Now, I am trying to delete a row from the displayed table. However, I am facing the following error:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/8.0.12 Server at 172.16.5.63 Port 80

I would be grateful for your help
My code

```
<?php 
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="entrydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
  $patient_name = $_POST['name'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
  $gene_name = $_POST['gene'];
  $method = $_POST['method'];
  $number_of_fragments = $_POST['fragments'];

  $sql_query = "INSERT INTO entry_details(name, gender, age, gene, method, fragments) VALUES ('$name', '$gender', '$age', '$gene', '$method', '$fragments')";

if (!$conn->query($sql_query))
{
echo "Connection error";
}

}

// delete row
if (isset($_POST['delete_id']))
{
  $delete_id = (int) $_POST['delete_id'];
  $sql_del="DELETE FROM `entry_details` WHERE ID='$delete_id'";
  $result_del=$link->query($sql_del);

  if (!$result_del)
  {
    echo "Delete ERROR";
  }
}

?>


// Display table
  <?php
  $sqlip = "SELECT * FROM entry_details";
  $resultip = $conn->query($sqlip);

  echo '
<table class= "input_table">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gene</th>
    <th>Method</th>
    <th>Fragments</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
  </tr>';
  if ($resultip->num_rows > 0)
    {
      while($rowip = $resultip->fetch_assoc())
        {
         echo '<tr>
         <td>'.$rowip['ID'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['name'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['gender'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['age'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['gene'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['method'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['fragments'].' </td>
         <td><a href=\"?delete_id={'.$rowip['ID'].'}\">Delete row</a></td>
         </tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';  
  ?>
```

Comment: try using $_GET instead of $_POST in case of delete

Comment: Still facing the same problem. My URL is showing this:
http://localhost/%22?delete_id={7}\%22

7 is the row id that I am trying to delete. Any clue from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try using mysqli real_escape_string() escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL query

```
<?php 
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="entrydb";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
         $patient_name = $_POST['name'];
         $gender = $_POST['gender'];
         $age = $_POST['age'];
         $gene_name = $_POST['gene'];
         $method = $_POST['method'];
         $number_of_fragments = $_POST['fragments'];

        $sql_query = "INSERT INTO entry_details(name, gender, age, gene, method, fragments) VALUES ('$name', '$gender', '$age', '$gene', '$method', '$fragments')";

        if (!$conn->query($sql_query))
        {
            echo "Connection error";
        }

    }

    // delete row
    if (isset($_GET['delete_id']))
    {
        $delete_id = (int) $_GET['delete_id'];
        $sql_del="DELETE FROM `entry_details` WHERE ID='$delete_id'";
        $result_del=$link->query($sql_del);

        if (!$result_del)
        {
            echo "Delete ERROR";
        }
    }

?>


// Display table
<?php
    $sqlip = "SELECT * FROM entry_details";
    $resultip = $conn->query($sqlip);

    echo '
            <table class= "input_table">
          <th>ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
           <th>Age</th>
           <th>Gene</th>
           <th>Method</th>
           <th>Fragments</th>
           <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>';
    if ($resultip->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($rowip = $resultip->fetch_assoc())
        {
         echo '<tr>
         <td>'.$rowip['ID'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['name'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['gender'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['age'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['gene'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['method'].' </td>
         <td>'.$rowip['fragments'].' </td>
         <td><a href="?delete_id='.$rowip['ID'].'">Delete row</a></td>
        </tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';  
?>
```

Comment: Tried it but, no luck.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please try one more time

Comment: It is working. Thank you Amit Sharma

Comment: Welcome! Could you please mark this as answer and give an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `bind_params()` function instead of using variables in your SQL query directly. Because sometimes I faced with this kinds of errors too.

Search about u

Comment: Tried it. Below is the code:

// delete row
if (isset($_POST['delete_id']))
{
  $delete_id = (int) $_POST['delete_id'];
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "DELETE FROM pcr_entry_details WHERE ID='$delete_id'");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $delete_id);
  // $sql_del="DELETE FROM `pcr_entry_details` WHERE ID='$delete_id'";
  // $result_del=$link->query($sql_del);

  if (!$result_del)
  {
    echo "Delete ERROR";
  }
}

Still facing the same error.